# PHP SimplePie Error: $item->get_enclosure() always return true

Tags: php, simplepie

Am trying to build a news reader using php SimplePie Library. When i try to get image from feed using code

```
if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure()){
    $imageLink = $enclosure->get_link(); 
    echo "<img src=\"$imageLink\">";
}
```

When i fetch feed from an rss feed which dont have an enclosure, it echo image tag with source as follows.

```
src="//?#"
```

The above code is working fine with feeds which have enclosures.

I also tried with code:

```
if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure()){
    if($imageLink = $enclosure->get_link()){
        echo "<img src=\"$imageLink\">";
    }
}
```

can someone tell me what i am doin wrong in these codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if $imageLink is assigned a value anywhere in your code. Most probably that could be the error. Use print_r or var_dump at each step of your code to fine where exactly is you code assigning that value to before mentioned variable

Answer (score 1):

Seems like $imageLink value is //?#, so if you do

```
if($imageLink = $enclosure->get_link())
```

The result is true...

check the exact value if there is no enclosure, and then change the condition... I.E

```
$imageLink = $enclosure->get_link();
if($imageLink !== "//?#") {
```

You can check the exact value using

```
if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure()){
    $imageLink = $enclosure->get_link(); 
    var_dump($imageLink);
}
```